# How to remove a trailing slash from the URL via the rewrite engine?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

In the root directory of my web-site I have a `.htaccess` file with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteRule ^blogs$ ./blogs.php
```

As a result, when a visitor requests the URL `mysite.com/blogs`, the PHP page `mysite.com/blogs.php` is processed and returned.

This behavior works fine. I would like to enhance it with this additional behavior: If the visitor requests the URL `mysite.com/blogs/` (notice the trailing slash), I would like him to be redirected tho the URL `mysite.com/blogs`. (I believe a redirect is necessary, since I don't want the trailing slash to appear in the address bar in the visitor's browser). Then, my above mentioned rewrite would kick in and `blogs.php` would be processed.

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^blogs/$ ./blogs [R=301]
RewriteRule ^blogs$ ./blogs.php
```

but that results in the URL changing to `http://mysite.loc/E:/Projects/mysite/blogs` without even redirecting. (I'm testing on local-host. `E:/Projects/mysite` is the root.)

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out `:-)`

The problem was the leading dot. I've removed it and now it works.

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/$ /blogs [R=301]
RewriteRule ^blogs$ ./blogs.php
```